# Python attribute resolution overhead

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, method-resolution-order

During attribute resolution, does Python check for each attribute if it exists in the class? If so, doesn't it incur a large overhead?

For example, checking the attribute `a.x`. Python must first check if `A.__dict__["x"]` is a data descriptor (as they override normal attribute lookups), meaning it should check the entire `__mro__` for data descriptors.
This in turn means that every attribute lookup in an instance dict, makes a lookup in the entire class mro which sounds like it's a HUGE overhead. Is this cached? And even if it is, what prevents the modification of one of the base classes, by dynamically adding a data descriptor? How will this theoretical cache get invalidated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class is already responsible for handling attribute lookups. But yes, to look up attributes the current class and the base classes are consulted, because the attribute could be a data descriptor.

That's because some objects are *special*, in that they can be bound to the instance or class (a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), *and* that they'll override any attribute with the same name on the instance if they are *data* descriptors (descriptors that support setting or deleting values).

All this is handled in the C implementation of the class's [`__getattribute__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) (usually inherited from `object.__getattribute__)`, and in C, access to both the instance and class namespaces is relatively cheap.

See the [*Descriptor HOWTO*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) for further details on how and why this is done.